# How to execute lightning component functions (apex or javascript controller) from a Visualforce page that includes the component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I created a lightning component that will house a drag and drop file uploader and handle all of its goings ons.

Then I bring it into my Visualforce page like so:

```
$Lightning.use('c:DropZoneComponentApp', function(){    
    $Lightning.createComponent('c:DropZoneComponent', {eventId: currentEvent.taskId}, 'eventDropzone', function(cmp){
        console.log('Component Created!', cmp);
        console.log(cmp.get('v.fileInfo'));
        //console.log(cmp.testingFunction()); <--Doesn't work
    });
});
```

I now want to be able to call functions of the lightning component when a button is pressed on my Visualforce page. just doing cmp.functionName() does not seem to work.

How do you accomplish this? I am OK triggering the AuraEnabled controller methods for the component, or the javascript controller methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `aura:method` to invoke lightning controller methods as follows. Store the generated component to a global variable and invoke the aura:method to call your controller action. You can either call lightning controller methods which could, in turn, call the @AuraEnabled Methods or use RemoteActions to call your apex class methods, it really depends on your use case.

> **Component:**

```
<aura:component access="global">

    <aura:method name="sampleMethod" action="{!c.doAction}" description="Sample method with parameters" access="global"> 
        <aura:attribute name="foo" type="String" default="parameter 1"/> 
        <aura:attribute name="bar" type="Object" /> 
    </aura:method>

    Inside Component

</aura:component>
```

> **Controller:**

```
({
    doAction : function(component, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParam('arguments');
        if (params) {
            console.log(params.foo);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(params.bar));
        }
    }
})
```

> **Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lightning" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var cmp; 

        $Lightning.use("c:TestApplication2", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:Component1",{},"lightning",
            function(component) {
              cmp = component; 
            });
        });

        var invoke_aura_method = function(){
            cmp.sampleMethod("Hello World ! ", {message : "I'm Jack Sparrow"});
        }

    </script>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Call Aura Method" onclick="invoke_aura_method();return false;"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

> **Example:**

[image: Sample Aura Method]

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was looking for. I had only figured out how to do this using lightning events, but this is much simpler and what I would prefer to do over using events.

Comment: Is there no way to use event based approach in VF?

Comment: You can - it all boils down to what your use case is  take a look into the following https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/lightning-visualforce-communication.html , Also there is $A.eventService.addHandler() with which you can listen to Aura Events and you can fire using "window.opener.$A.get("e.mynamespace:externalEvent")" , here are a couple of samples http://www.sfdcstuff.com/2017/07/firing-event-from-lightning-component.html , https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_external.htm